# Chrome Opens, But No Windows Appear

Tags: google-chrome

I'm just about at the end of my rope with this. I'm trying to install Chrome 42 on an Ubuntu 14.10 machine and I'm running into some issues. Chrome installs fine, but when I run it, nothing shows up. The process starts correctly, but there are no windows that appear. When `google-chome` is run in the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
[2384:2384:0417/014315:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(240)] Invalid url pattern: chrome://print/*
```

and

```
[2436:2436:0417/014315:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(345)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
```

I've also tried the beta and dev branches of Chrome, as well as Chromium, but to no avail. I have a Radeon HD 6850 GPU and I am using the default Ubuntu Radeon drivers. Earlier today I was getting the same issue on a Fedora installation, with the exact same errors. Thanks for your help, and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue while trying numerous solutions.  For me the problem turned out to be simply viewing the wrong desktop.  I have an external monitor and the laptop lid closed.  I found Chrome running on the other screen.  Turned off that monitor in settings and chrome launches in the primary window.  Turn on Workspace switcher to see all available workspaces.